# Why am I getting the error "cannot resolve method "x" in "x""?

Tags: java

The purpose of this program is to create a class and tester class for a select object(in my case a monitor), with at least one overloaded method. And in the client class, I have to instantiate at least three instances of the object. So far I believe I've finished the first class with the declaration of methods, getters and setters, and constructors. The problem occurs in my tester class, where I get the error "Cannot resolve method 'MonitorV82' in 'Monitor V82'. I don't know for sure why I'm getting this error, any advice?

My first class is:

```java
public class MonitorV82
{
    private double l;
    private double h;


    //one parameter constructor, all private instance variables initialized
    public MonitorV82(double monitor1Height) {
        //2.When this gets name1(jupiter), it designates "jupiter" to the variable "n"
        h = monitor1Height;
        l = (monitor1Height * 1.77);
    }

    //two parameter constructor
    public MonitorV82(double monitor1Height, double monitor1Length){
        //3.When this gets name1(jupiter), and a double, it sets jupiter to "n" and the diameter to "d"
        h = monitor1Height;
        l = monitor1Length;
    }

    public double getMon1height() { return h; }

    public double getMon1Length() {
        return l;
    }


    public void setMon1height(double name) { h = name; }

    public void setMon1Length(double diam) {
        l = diam;
    }

    public String monType(int resolution)
    {
        String monitType = "";
        if (resolution == 1080) {
            monitType = "lenovo";

        } else if (resolution == 4000) {
            monitType = "samsung";
        }
        return monitType;
    }

    //overloaded method
    public String monType(int pixLength,int pixHeight)
    {
        String monitType = "";
        if (pixHeight == 1080) {
            monitType = "lenovo";

        } else if (pixHeight == 4000) {
            monitType = "samsung";
        }
        return monitType;

    }


}
```

My tester class(where the error is) is:

```
public class V8Tester {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double length1 = 32.2;
        double height1 = 51.8;

        double length2 = 31.8;
        double height2 = 50.6;

        int resolution = 0;

        MonitorV82 monit1 = new MonitorV82(length1);
        resolution = monit1.MonitorV82(height1);

    }
}
```

I am still learning Java in school so please don't roast me if something seems obvious or simple. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `monit1.MonitorV82(height1)`? There is no method with that name; and there is also no method returning an `int` (which you'd need, since you're trying to assign the result to `resolution`).

Comment: Because it's not a function in `MonitorV82`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because there is no method `MonitorV82`, only a constructor. Also you are trying to instantiate the `int` variable resolution with a `MonitorV82` object, which is not possible, because the compiler expects an `int` value.

If you want the resolution that refers to the pixel count of the `MonitorV82` object with known pixel height, you first need to find out it's pixel length. You can do this by using your `getMon1length()` method and the calculate the resolution by length * height. Ultimately what I think you are trying to do is:

```
int heightMonit1 = monit1.getMon1height();

int resolution = (int)length1 * (int)heightMonit1;
```

You need to type cast, because you want to instantiate the `int` variable `resolution` with a calculation of double values.

You could however also use your second constructor and do:

```
MonitorV82 monit1 = new MonitorV82(length1, height1);

int resolution = (int)monit1.getMon1height() * (int)monit1.getMon1length();
```

Answer (score 1):

Before answering the question in the title, you need the answer to this question:

### What is a constructor in Java?

A constructor in Java is a special method used to "construct" (build, instantiate, etc.) objects. A constructor follows these basic rules:

1. The name of the constructor should match exactly the class name. In your case, `MonitorV82` is this name.
2. A constructor doesn't have a return type. The `new` operator is responsible for returning a new object matching the type of the class in which the constructor is being invoked.

Knowing this, let's address the original question: Why the error? Because in `MonitorV82` there is only a constructor a with matching name, but not a regular method with the same name. Consider my example below

```
public class Test {

  private String name = "default";

  // constructor #1
  public Test() {}

  // constructor #2
  public Test(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  // method #1
  public void Test() {
    System.out.println(name);
  }

  // method #2  
  public void Test(String name) {
    System.out.println(name);
  }
}
```

Notice that in the code above, I have two constructors and two methods with the same name (matching case) and same parameters. **This is allowed in Java although this is STRONGLY discouraged due to how confusing it can get**.

### What does this mean for you?

To create `monit1`, you need to invoke a **CONSTRUCTOR**. Once you construct the object, you cannot use it to invoke a constructor. You use objects to invoke non-static, accessible methods. Based on this, the line

```
MonitorV82 monit1 = new MonitorV82(length1);
```

is totally fine. However, the set resolution line is not `resolution = monit1.MonitorV82(height1);` because you have no **METHOD** named `MonitorV82` (you just have a constructor with a matching name). You fix this by creating a method in your class that does exactly that. Since method names should be descriptive of their function, creating a method named `setResolution` or `calculateResolution` should be fine. What you should not do is used an ambiguous name; especially using the same name as the constructor.

Lastly, I will leave you with this small piece of advice: Just because the language allows you to do something, that does not mean that it is correct or OK to do so. My code example (along with this lengthy explanation) should've illustrated this point.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> Why am I getting the error "cannot resolve method "x" in "x""?

Because your last line tries to call a method named `MethodV82` which does not exist on an instance of the class named `MethodV82`.

## Details

Firstly, you should have indicated which line of code is causing that error.

You have at least one offending line, that last line. The code `monit1.MonitorV82(height1)` makes no sense. That code is trying to call a method named `MonitorV82` on the instance named `monit1`. But of course there is no such method. Thus the error « Cannot resolve method ».

I cannot follow your logic, so I cannot give a fixed replacement code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of constructors.
I guess that what you want to do with your `monit1.MonitorV82(height1)` is to set the height of your monit1 instance to height1.

You need to call the setter to do so, not a constructor. The constructor is not known as a class method, that is why your error occurs. Use

```
monit1.setMon1height(height1);
```

Next, I think that you are trying to retrieve a resolution from your monitor, but you have no method inside of your MonitorV82 with this aim so I suggest that you create a method for this such as

```
public int computeResolution() {
    return this.h * this.l;
}
```

In your test class you end up with:

```
public class V8Tester {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    double length1 = 32.2;
    double height1 = 51.8;

    double length2 = 31.8;
    double height2 = 50.6;

    int resolution = 0;

    MonitorV82 monit1 = new MonitorV82(length1);
    monit1.setMon1height(height1);
    resolution = monit1.computeResolution();

}
```

}

Edit: Even the instantiation of your monit1 does not seem correct. The only one parameter constructor you have is based on height and you are calling it with length1

Edit2: My example of computeResolution() will probably end up with an exception as I am returning an int from a compute action on doubles. But I think that it is not the main issue here